# Using Index to copy all rows that have a quantity in col A from all sheets onto 1 sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking for some assistance on excel, I have a workbook with approx 15 sheets that have the same exact layout and I am trying to use an INDEX/MATCH formula to pull all rows that have a quantity in column A to another sheet in the workbook to create a list but I keep getting N/A. I need the data to be live so that if any of the sheets are updated the summary page is also upto date.
I have previously had this working in google sheets using a Query function but can't make it work in excel. Any help would be much appreciated.

Tried this formula:
=INDEX(Equipment!$A$4:$A$676,MATCH(A1,Equipment!$A$4:$R$676,-1))

Comment: Help us to help you; **post your formula.**

Comment: You will want vba to do this.

Comment: Any assistance on how to do this in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example to show how INDEX(), Match() and INDEX() & MATCH() work together:

[image]